# Android app for motion blur

Tags: android, web-apps, image-processing, image-editor, image-editing

Is there any android app which can give my image a 'motion' blur effect with 'direction'(angle or orientation) I can change?

There are many image editors in playstore but no one has motion blur function I want.

I know that gimp has the feature but it runs on PC and I can't use PC now for some reason.

So I need to use android smartphone application featuring motion blur I explained above.(I have Samsung Galaxy S5 which supports Android OS.)

Link of webpage which supports the motion blur is also welcoming.

I'd appreciate it if anyone recommended me an good app or webpage I need.